# Deployed app engine isn't gzipping my content

Tags: angular, express, google-app-engine

### Final update

Should be [rolling out end of this month](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117814186#comment5).

---

Pretty odd here, I have deployed a few sites to app engine on standard env NodeJS. It's late but hopefully I've been doing something wrong.

I have a base scaffold Angular 6 app that I've deployed to app engine, and while the locally ran server is giving me gzipped content, the deployed app is not.  Pretty standard universal `server.ts`:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import * as express from 'express';
import compression from 'compression';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { join } from 'path';

enableProdMode();

const app = express();
app.use(compression()); // <== Definitely using compression here

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {
  AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  LAZY_MODULE_MAP
} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine(
  'html',
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)]
  })
);

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Devtools for the deployed site is showing both full file size and the response headers are not "gzip", although the accept-encoding is the usual `gzip, br` etc.

Locally, it's gzipped.

I'm stumped.

### Edit:

Just as a bump, I made a very basic application to show the issue.  I've read all the docs, and I just really don't get why, if anything, the express middleware is not being "allowed" to serve the gzipped content via the `compression` middleware.

Request headers for the largest asset:

```
:authority: ng-universal-test-220902.appspot.com
:method: GET
:path: /main.119034af43b36e354210.js
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://ng-universal-test-220902.appspot.com/
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36
```

Response headers for the same request:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
cache-control: public, max-age=0
content-length: 642804
content-type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 29 Oct 2018 02:26:38 GMT
etag: W/"9cef4-166bda0e164"
last-modified: Mon, 29 Oct 2018 02:22:09 GMT
server: Google Frontend
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cloud-trace-context: 8d126079c95f2e6bbced4265c46a87ca
x-powered-by: Express
```

[image: Network panel showing no Content-Encoding headers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117814186#comment5), this will roll out end of November.

### Update

It looks like this has been rolled out.